# Diferencia entre "andar", "caminar" e "ir"

Tags: gramática, verbos, uso-de-palabras

> Caminando en dirección al bosque, vi a mi amiga Sylvia.
>
> Andando en dirección al bosque, vi a mi amiga Sylvia.
>
> Yendo en dirección al bosque, vi a mi amiga Sylvia.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ellos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes **ir** al bosque de diferentes maneras: caminando, en bicicleta, en coche. Por supuesto, dependerá del contexto.

**Caminar** y **andar** denotan el mismo tipo de movimiento: a pie. De acuerdo con el diccionario **caminar** es preferentemente transitivo (lleva complemento directo) y **andar** es preferentemente intransitivo (no lleva complemento directo), pero en último término ambos pueden ser transitivos o intransitivos.